# Chromium page search bar?

Tags: chromium

I was reading a webpage and hit some unknown buttons on my keyboard and a search bar popped up in the top right hand corner of the browser under the tool bar and any thing you type in the bar is highlighted on the page your on. How do I get this bar to appear?
I am on Ubuntu 12.04 and my Chromium version is the latest in the repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That bar is named **Find bar**, it appear using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> shortcut key and is used to find some text on the current page:

[image: find bar]

The **Find bar** can be closed by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

Answer (score 1):

You've accidentally used the key combo `ctrl+F`, it enables the default search function that browsers have. You can close it by using the same key combo, or the close icon that is there on the search icon.

Comment: thank you, and ctrl-f just opens it, wont close it, the closes fine  graphicly thought, thought it was cool and useful, wanted to know how to use it

Comment: cheers mate, glad it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can make it appear using Ctrl+F